# How to pull only part of a text field from DB in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Rails 4 app with text fields containing very long strings (sometimes 10s of thousands of characters). I'd like to pull only the first 500 characters in an index view, in order to make the app more performant. I'm not sure how to do that or even if that's the best method to improve performance. Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many SQL languages support a LEFT function, which is a scalar value that returns the first n characters of a string.

In SQLServer, for instance, you can use

```
SELECT LEFT(text, 500)
```

This works provided the datatype isn't text or ntext (both are deprecated).

If you're using a model in Rails, then you can use

```
MyModel.select("LEFT(COLUMN, 500)")
```

If your SQL supports this type of function. Make sure to combine this with your other values into one SQL query.

Comment: Thanks! I'm using postgresql, which does support left, but I was hoping to find more of a Rails Way to do this, if possible. If there simply isn't one, I'll accept this answer.

Comment: `left` will work just fine in PostgreSQL for what it's worth, and doesn't care about the data type. `text` in PostgreSQL is just an alias for `varchar` anyway, and there's no `ntext` (some kind of SQL Server unicode type?).

Comment: ntext is the old unicode version of text, if I'm correct on this. It's probably SQLServer only; I'm not too sure.

Comment: This is probably your best solution; Rails doesn't have any abstract concept of "get part of a field from the DB" as far as I know.

Comment: That's what I thought. Just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something. :-) Thanks all - especially @JimPedid!

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else that's coming across this, the syntax for Jim Pedid's answer is actually:

```
MyModel.select("LEFT(COLUMN, 500) as COLUMN")
```

The reason is that the left function returns a column called "LEFT" instead of "COLUMN" and unless your model contains a property named "LEFT" of the same type, rails won't know what to do with it. Renaming the column back to "COLUMN" again makes sure rails will let you access it. Hopefully this will spare someone some unnecessary debugging.

Aditional live (working) example from my app:

```
Post.select("id, title, left(body, 100) as body")
```

(I would have posted this as a comment on Jim Pedid's answer but doesn't have enough reputation  yet to do so.)

Answer (score 2):

You could try starting with just rails and the data being sent over the wire, i.e.

use `[0..100]` to get a sub-string and then that is all that is sent as html, e.g.

```
irb(main):006:0> Group.first.group_description[0..100]
  Group Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `groups`.* FROM `groups` ORDER BY group_name LIMIT 1
=> "Charting Tools, Gems and Plugins"
```

This lets you try this first to see if it is enough before hacking the sql.

Comment: I'm currently using rails' truncate method to make sure all that data isn't sent to the client, but I'd like to find a Rails Way to prevent it from even being pulled from the database, if possible.